# In AWS step function definitions, how do I pass a parameter into a properties array?

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

Using the following step function state definition, I want to reference the month, date, year parameters I have passed into it inside the command runner arguments. Right now the join evaluates into  `"--src=s3://arn:aws:s3::: bababucketName/$.YEAR/$.MONTH/$.DAY/"` unexpectedly. Is there a way to use the step function parameters in the cloud formation function?

```
"CopyFromS3": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
    "Parameters": {
    "ClusterId.$": "$.cluster.ClusterId",
    "Step": {
        "Name": "CopyFromS3",
        "HadoopJarStep": {
        "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
        "Args": [
            "s3-dist-cp",
            {
            "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ 
                "--src=s3://",
                { "Ref": "VehicleDataBucket" },
                "telemetry/",
                "$.YEAR",
                "/",
                "$.MONTH",
                "/",
                "$.DAY",
                "/"
                ]
            ]
            },
            "--dest=hdfs:///output"
        ]
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at States.Array intrinsic function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html

Also AWS just released this new tool to make it easier to develop workflows. That should help you compose your state machine definition. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/workflow-studio.html